# Why has primaryVariant property been deprecated?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, material-design, themes

I am working on flutter a flutter project and using `MaterialApp` while providing the `ColorScheme` I used `primaryVariant` property but now [Official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme/primaryVariant.html) is saying that it is deprecated and asks to use `primaryContainer`. But I could not find any reasons for that what was wrong with `primaryVariant`? Why has it been deprecated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because of the changes in Material Design 3. Use `primaryContainer` for elements needing less emphasis than primary, instead of `primaryVariant`.

Here's the pull request affects this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/93427.

You can check the Material Design 3 doc for more detail: https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/color-roles.